# Solution of ODE: $(f'(x))^2 - (f(x))^2+ 1 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A few days ago, I came upon the discovery that the arc length of $ f(x) = \cosh(x) $ is equal to the area between any two points of its points.  It made me curious to find other functions that satisfy this property.  I've found a few mentions of this specific example on mathstackexchange, but I haven't found a question seeking a more general result.

I felt that the first step was evidently setting the area equal to the arc length so that 
$$\int f(x) dx = \int \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$$

Since we're assuming equality, I removed the integrand and squared both sides to get rid of the square root (I assume this will not change any results since both sides of the equation should have the same sign - please correct me if I'm mistaken), and after simplifying:

$$(f'(x))^2-(f(x))^2+1=0$$

I've found that $f(x) = \cosh(x+c)$ (where $c$ is a constant) and $f(x) = 1$ are both solutions, but this was purely through inspection.  Does this differential equation have other solutions (specifically, I'm interested in finding a general solution), and if so, what are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be written as $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{y^2-1}$$
$$\implies \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}=\int dx$$
Now substitute $y=\sec t$ to get:
$$\int \frac{\sec t\tan t dt}{\tan t}=x+C$$
$$\implies \ln |\sec t+\tan t|=x+C$$
$$\implies \sec t+\tan t=C_1e^x$$
$$\implies y+\sqrt{y^2-1}=C_1e^x$$

Comment: Thank you - it's so simple now that I see how it's done!  The only thing I'm curious about now is why y = 1 works as a solution, because it doesn't seem like it's a solution to your implicit equation.  Is it just an exceptional case or am I missing it somewhere in your equation?

Comment: @Daniel I don't see $y=1$ from my way but yes you're right it is a solution. Interesting!

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Since we're interested in finding a family of functions such that area equals arc length, our function, y, must always be greater than zero, since arc length is always positive.  When you solved the differential equation by 'splitting' the differentials, we had to remove the function y = 1 from the domain, otherwise the denominator equals 0 and the integral is undefined.  So I think your family of solutions plus the particular solution y = 1 should cover all functions satisfying the arc length = area property.

Comment: @Daniel, ahh nice observation!